# Is there "not...till"? Does its meaning equal to "not...until"?

Tags: difference, prepositions, negation

Is there "not...till"? Does its meaning equal to "not...until"?
Does the sentence "A body at rest will not move till a force is exerted on it" sound natural?

Comment: I think you will find "till" only in informal speech and litarary works. There is no difference in meaning and whether it sounds natural depends on the context and situation. Any specific reason for not using "until"?

Comment: Same question in EL&U: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6989/what-is-the-difference-between-till-and-until

Comment: @jinawee I visited the link you posted. There it says when negative sentences are concerned, using "till" is not correct. And hence the sentence in OP is not correct. Am I right?

Comment: @Man_From_India I'm not a native but I'll give my view. As you can see in the comments there, some people find more natural using "till" in particular negative conditionals (I'd prefer "till" rather than "until" in "I'm not _gonna_ say a word till I get a lawyer" for the sake of fludity) . So you can't say whether is correct or not, it will just sound different. In the OP's case, "until" might fit better, but "till" is fine (if it were in a high school texbook, "till" would possibly seem strange).

Answer (score 1):

The word `till` is a synonym of `until`, so the meaning is the same, yes. `Until` is the more standard word.

It can also be written `'til` or `til`. (Both are less formal than `until`)

**Edit:** Note that `until` is the preferred word today, so `until` will usually sound most natural. Other meanings of `till` are even included in this graph:

[image]

Comment: The ***'til*** spelling represents a misconception that the word is abbreviated from ***until***, when in fact it is the older, more basic word.  I suggest using the standard spelling ***till*** instead.

Comment: Or just use **until**, as it is far more popular word today, used over 90% of the time (according to an [ngram query](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=until+%2F+(until+%2B+till)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3))

Comment: @snailplane Do you have a source for that? I always assumed 'til came from until, and I use `'til` exclusively (and even scoff at `till` users).

Comment: @pabo Sure, pretty much any source you like.  [EtymOnline](http://etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=until&searchmode=none) is one that's freely available.  The Oxford English Dictionary says: "ME. (originally northern) *untill*, f. ON. *und* (retained only in *unz, undz* = *und es*), = Goth. *und* (and *untē*), OS. *und* (usually *unt*), OFris. *und* (*ont*), up to, as far as + *till* (*till prep.* and *conj*).]".  You can, of course, scoff for whatever reason you like, but scoffing at someone for preferring the standard spelling of a word is a rather strange choice.

Comment: @snailplane err.. the oldest spelling isn't the same as the standard spelling.

Comment: @Qubei No, but *till* is most certainly standard.  The non-standard *'til* indicates in spelling the reanalysis of *till* as an abbreviation of *until*.  It's certainly interesting that speakers like yourself conceptualize it this way, and I don't have anything against the spelling *'til* myself, but I recommend avoiding it because it may convince people that the speller is ignorant.

Comment: The [AHD](http://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=till) suggests that *'til* is now acceptable as an alternative respelling of *till*: "*Till* is actually the older word, with *until* having been formed by the addition to it of the prefix *un-*, meaning "up to." In the 18th century the spelling *'till* became fashionable, as if *till* were a shortened form of *until*. Although *'till* is now nonstandard, *'til* is sometimes used in this way and is considered acceptable, though it is etymologically incorrect."  Of course, *till* is still standard and in widespread use.

Comment: My world is shattered. I will start using `till` exclusively, and have started making a list of all the people I have previously misjudged by their use of it. Apologies to ensue.

Comment: For reference, *the Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)* has [786 results for `' til`](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=32391149) (because of how the corpus is put together, you have to put a space after the apostrophe when you search) and [12060 results for `till`](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/?c=coca&q=32391156).  That's about a 15:1 ratio in favor of *till*.